# JavaScript and C++ Callback Function with Arguments

Tags: javascript, c++, function, callback

How would I achieve the following JavaScript implementation of callbacks in C++? Below is taken from a JavaScript snippet. I'd like to achieve the same functionality:

```
var playAdBreak = function(adbreak, callback) 
{
    var x;
    playSingle(x, function() { playAdBreak.call(this, adbreak, callback); });
};

var playSingle = function(abc, callback) 
{

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are under C++11 environment, you can use lambda, `std::function`. Below code doesn't have same functionality, but it can convert into like below except for : C++ lambda is not closure and there is no `this` for a function.

```
auto playSingle = [&](const T &abc, std::function<void()> callback) {

}

auto playAdBreak = [&](const Y &adbreak, std::function<void()) callback) {
  T x;
  playSingle(x, [=]() { playAdBreak(adbreak, callback); });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! But by any chance do you know an alternative way of implementing this? the trouble i'm having is passing the parameters into playAdBreak(adbreak, callback) as part of the callback function

Answer (score 1):

The modest way of doing it that I can think is

```
void callBackDefinition()
{
    printf("I was called");
}

void callBackExecutor(void (*callBack))
{
    callBack();
}

main()
{
    callBackExecutor(&callBackDefinition);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The trouble i'm actually having is passing the parameters into playAdBreak(adbreak, callback) as part of the callback function. Still trying to figure that out...